# Angularjs - watching a promise - getting undefined

Tags: angularjs, promise

I know that the templates can bind to either a promise or a real value, and when that value changes the template is updated.

I want to do something similar in a directive, where I watch for changes to a promise and reload the data in the directive when that promise is updated.

However, when I watch a promise, it seems to register the change but then is immediately set to 'undefined'.

See http://plnkr.co/edit/eOjkuvyrQvKhkAbVLGVG?p=preview

As you can see the template is updated with no problem, but if you check the console, the 'isNotAPromise' watch works as expected, but the 'isAPromise' watch is triggered twice, both with 'undefined'.

Any clues?

Here's the code to make SO happy:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $q) {
  var c;
  c = 1;
  setInterval(function() {
    c = c + 1;
    console.log('---------------');
    console.log(['c changed to ', c]);
    return $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.isNotAPromise = c;
      return $scope.isAPromise = $q.when(c);
    });
  }, 1000);
  $scope.$watch('isAPromise', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    return console.log(['isAPromise changed', oldVal, newVal]);
  });
  return $scope.$watch('isNotAPromise', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    return console.log(['isNotAPromise changed', oldVal, newVal]);
  });
});
```

Thanks,
Roy

Comment: This is related to the AngularJS life cycle. There are other SO answers about this. The $watch is called at least twice at the beginning, so you may have a check for undefined and for newval == oldval.

Comment: Thanks jpmorin, but this question is more about the differences between promises and non-promises - the values returned to the watch for these scenarios are different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a timestamp to determine when the two watches were triggering:

```
console.log [+new Date(), 'isAPromise changed', oldVal, newVal]
```

Sample output:

```js
["c changed to ", 3] app.js:12
[1366223960472, "isAPromise changed", 2, undefined] app.js:19
["isNotAPromise changed", 2, 3] app.js:22
[1366223960473, "isAPromise changed", undefined, 3]
```

So, the two watches on `isAPromise` are firing 1 millisecond apart.  I'll guess that what happens is that when `$q.when(c)` is first assigned to `$scope.isAPromise`, it is `undefined` because the promise isn't resolved yet.  Then the promise is resolved (probably during the very next $digest loop) and `isAPromise` is then set to the value of the (resolved?) promise.

Comment: This is probably it.  I have a few more ideas for tests - will update the question with those after I 'plunk' them