# Strange behavior when watching a promise

Tags: angularjs, promise, watch

I have a strange behavior when watching a promise with angularjs 1.0.2.

Instead of getting the old and new values after a promise has changed my function is called twice. 
The first time with the new value undefined, the second time with the old value undefined.

Here a is demo (the results appear in the console) : http://jsfiddle.net/franckv/BqmJv/2/

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

function Ctrl($scope, $timeout, $q) {
    var j = 0;

    $scope.model = {
        aPromise: $q.when(0),

        getAPromise: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(++j);
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        updateAPromise: function () {
            console.log('\nupdateAPromise called');
            $scope.model.aPromise = this.getAPromise();
        }
    }

    $scope.$watch('model.aPromise', function (newPromise, oldPromise) {
        console.log('newPromise:' + newPromise + ', oldPromise:' + oldPromise);
    });

}
```

Any idea why it behaves like that and how to get the same behavior as a normal value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs - watching a promise - getting undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067081/angularjs-watching-a-promise-getting-undefined)